# How to check the differentiability of $|\cos x|+|\sin(2-x)|$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

$f(x)=|cosx|+|sin(2−x)|$ 
At which of the following point $f$ is not differentiable?

1. $(2n+1)\pi/2$
2. $n\pi$
3. $n\pi+2$
4. $n\pi/2$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

When I tried to solve it graphically, I got that $|\sin x|$ is not differentiable at $n\pi$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $|\cos x|$ is not differentiable at $(n+1)\pi/2$ (I am not sure about this one). So the given function must not be differentiable at option (1) and option (3). Am I correct?

(I know this is duplicate but from there I could not get the answer satisfactorily and I can not even comment so I am posting it here)

Comment: Your solution seems correct. What do you expect from an answer?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about  the differentiability of $|cosx|$ and I am also confused among the options so I expect a concrete proof of the correct answers.

Comment: $cos(x) = sin(x + \pi / 2)$, so it's differentiability is shifted by $\pi/2$ wrt $sin(x)$

Comment: Got it!Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The values at which the function is potentially non-differentiable is where the individual terms are non-differentiable, i.e. where the argument of the absolute values change sign. These are the odd multiples of half-Pi, and the multiples of Pi plus two.

As Pi is irrational, these points never coincide, so that the "non-differentiabilities" cannot cancel each other.

Comment: Actually I could not understand ""non differentiabilities can not cancel each other". How do they cancel and how can they not? (Actually I am preparing for an exam all by myself and with the help of internet so I think I am having problem in basics, I will appreciate your help)

Comment: @Huny: consider the case of $2|\sin x|-|\sin 2x|$.

Comment: Thanks!! Now I got it.

Comment: Also I am confused for the fourth option. $|cosx|$ is not differentiable at the odd multiples of $\pi/2$ and here n can be both(even or odd) so how can we assure the differentiability of the function at this point?

Comment: @Huny: the question is indeed ambiguous.